# Issues extracting public key from certificate.crt using MAC Machine

Tags: encryption, openssl, certificate, public-key-encryption

I am trying to extract a public key from a certificate.crt when using my Mac but seem to be getting errors. this seems to work on Windows but not mac.

```
openssl x509 -in lee/EncryptionCert.crt -pubkey -noout -out test.txt
```

I got the error below

```
unable to load certificate
140704374125376:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start 
line:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/97f6331a-ba75-11ed-a4bc- 
863efbbaf80d/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl- 
3.3/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:694:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Comment: How are you moving or otherwise creating the file? Check _exactly_ what is in the BEGIN line in the file; with Linux/GNU I like `cat -vET` but I don't know if Mac (BSD) has that, if not `od -c` is good enough.